# How to move log files in /var/log/journal to free disk space without losing logs?

Tags: debian, logs, disk-usage, systemd-journald, disk-cleanup

I'd like to later check if there is a way / software to easily scan logs for issues one should look into² and if such exists scan all logs, including old logs. This is why for now I'd like to keep the logs of my Debian11/KDE machine rather than just delete them or set a datastorage-limit with e.g. `journalctl --vacuum-size=500M`.

As they're taking lots of disk space on the small root partition, I'd like to move them.

**How can I move the log files to another partition (on another drive that isn't always mounted) without causing problems with the ongoing logging and read these logs also from there?** I hope that at some point the above can be carried out within a GUI, preferably `KSystemLog`, which reads and shows the journal logs from the location they have been move to and the current location on the root partition.

---

So far these two options don't seem to be appropriate as is:

```
sudo cp /var/log/kern.log /media/..../kern.log
sudo truncate -s 0 /var/log/kern.log
```

The above would copy the file elsewhere and then truncate the local file, but this doesn't seem to be a good way that allows properly reading the logs etc.

```
service rsyslog stop
mv /var/log/audit /home/
ln -s /home/audit /var/log/audit
service rsyslog start
```

The above would create a symbolic link which could be a good approach if the partition was always mounted.

---

(Other related questions that this question is not about would be how to enable limitless logging but at the same time prevent for example many duplicate messages from inflating the logs' file-sizes and which configured-by-default software can to date already smartly scan logs.)

² for example all entries with the type "error", or summaries that combine many similar log entries, or most frequent log-entries, or messages known to be actual problems, or intrusion-attempts, or all security-issue-related entries, ...

Comment: Why not move `/var` to its own partition/drive entirely?

Comment: Because the drive is not always mounted, I'd like to keep the most recent logs on the local root partition and even if there was an easy non-breaking way to add a new partition dedicated to logs or `/var` on a small fully encrypted SSD drive with a separate home partition, it would be too small for the large logs due to which they would have to be moved at some point as well.

Comment: Have you looked at `logrotate(8)`?  It won't solve the "not always mounted" issue, but will give you old logs that you can  move at your leisure.

Comment: I think using both `logrotate` (configuring it if the default config isn't sufficient) and (manually moving the files via) `sudo mv /var/log/journal/../system@* /media/.../` could be the best solution. However, that doesn't solve the reading from all logs part. I guess one could then simply create symbolic links with `ln -s` to all the moved log-files or shortcuts within KDE's Dolphin (drag&drop and select "Link here").